# Is there a way to force reloadData on a UICollectionView using RxSwift?

Tags: rx-swift

I have a UICollectionView bound to an array of entities using BehaviorSubject and all is fine, data is loaded from the network and displayed correctly.

The problem is, based on user action, I'd like to change the CellType used by the UICollectionView and force the collection to re-create all cells, how do I do that?

My bind code looks like:

```
self.dataSource.bind(to: self.collectionView!.rx.items) {
   view, row, data in

   let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)

   var ret: UICollectionViewCell? = nil
   if (self.currentReuseIdentifier == reuseIdentifierA) {
      // Dequeue cell type A and bind it to model
      ret = cell
   } else {
      // Dequeue cell type B and bind it to model
      ret = cell
   }

   return ret!
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

The general way to solve problems in Rx is to think of what you want the output effect to be and what input effects can affect it.

In your case, the output effect is the display of the table view. You have identified two input effects "data is loaded from the network" and "user action". In order to make your observable chain work properly, you will have to combine your two input effects in some way to get the behavior you want. I can't say how that combination should take place without more information, but here is an article explaining most of the combining operators available: https://medium.com/@danielt1263/recipes-for-combining-observables-in-rxswift-ec4f8157265f

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can emit an empty list then an actual data to force the collectionView to reload like so:

```
dataSource.onNext([])
dataSource.onNext([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use different data type to create cell

```swift
import Foundation
import RxDataSources

enum SettingsSection {
    case setting(title: String, items: [SettingsSectionItem])
}

enum SettingsSectionItem {
    case bannerItem(viewModel: SettingSwitchCellViewModel)
    case nightModeItem(viewModel: SettingSwitchCellViewModel)
    case themeItem(viewModel: SettingCellViewModel)
    case languageItem(viewModel: SettingCellViewModel)
    case contactsItem(viewModel: SettingCellViewModel)
    case removeCacheItem(viewModel: SettingCellViewModel)
    case acknowledgementsItem(viewModel: SettingCellViewModel)
    case whatsNewItem(viewModel: SettingCellViewModel)
    case logoutItem(viewModel: SettingCellViewModel)
}

extension SettingsSection: SectionModelType {
    typealias Item = SettingsSectionItem

    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .setting(let title, _): return title
        }
    }

    var items: [SettingsSectionItem] {
        switch  self {
        case .setting(_, let items): return items.map {$0}
        }
    }

    init(original: SettingsSection, items: [Item]) {
        switch original {
        case .setting(let title, let items): self = .setting(title: title, items: items)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SettingsSection>(configureCell: { dataSource, tableView, indexPath, item in
            switch item {
            case .bannerItem(let viewModel),
                 .nightModeItem(let viewModel):
                let cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: switchReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? SettingSwitchCell)!
                cell.bind(to: viewModel)
                return cell
            case .themeItem(let viewModel),
                 .languageItem(let viewModel),
                 .contactsItem(let viewModel),
                 .removeCacheItem(let viewModel),
                 .acknowledgementsItem(let viewModel),
                 .whatsNewItem(let viewModel),
                 .logoutItem(let viewModel):
                let cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? SettingCell)!
                cell.bind(to: viewModel)
                return cell
            }
        }, titleForHeaderInSection: { dataSource, index in
            let section = dataSource[index]
            return section.title
        })

        output.items.asObservable()
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
            .disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
```

1. [RxDataSources](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources)
2. [swiftHub](https://github.com/khoren93/SwiftHub/tree/master/SwiftHub/Modules/Settings)

Comment: That works if you have all your mapping (itemType -> cellIdentifier) from the beginning... but if you change the reusableCell identifier you're using for a certain item type you'll run into the same problem, how can you force "configureCell" to happen again so you can change your cell type.

Comment: @ftofoli like reload cell at indexPath?